# Inequality very difficult to show

Tags: integration, inequality, integral-inequality

1) $\int _0^1\:\frac{x^n}{x^n+1}dx\ge \int _0^1\:\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^{n+1}+1}dx$ but I dont want to use $I_{n+1}-I_n$
2) How we can prove with direct comparison test for ( Improper ) Integrals that is bounded: $I_n\:=\int _n^{n+1}\:\frac{2x-1}{x}dx$

P.S.: Have any idea how we can solve the second problem?

Comment: can you show that $\frac{x^n}{x^n+ 1} \ge \frac{x^{n+1}}{x^{n+1}+ 1}$ for all $n$ and all $0 \le x \le 1$? And if so, do you see how this would prove your inequality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I_n:=\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{x^n+1}dx=\int_0^1\left(1-\frac1{x^n+1}\right)dx=1-\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^n+1}$$

$$I_{n+1}=\int_0^1\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^{n+1}+1}dx=\int_0^1\left(1-\frac1{x^{n+1}+1}\right)dx=1-\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^{n+1}+1}$$

Now, it is trivial that for $\;x\in[0,1]\;$ we have

$$\frac1{x^{n+1}+1}\ge\frac1{x^n+1}\ge0$$

and both functions are non-negative in the unit interval, and from here that $\;I_n\ge I_{n+1}\;$ .

As for (2): observe that

$$I_n=\int_n^{n+1}\left(2-\frac1x\right)\le\int_n^{n+1}2\,dx=2$$

By the way, this is *not* an improper integral.

Comment: why we need to use the fact? because we see $x^n+1\ge \:x^n$ and I think we can anticipate that is >0

Comment: @Lucas What "fact"? Didn't understand your comment.

Comment: I mean why you use this formula $\frac{a}{a+1}=1-\frac{1}{a+1}$ ? to show $I_n\le 1$? or to show $\frac{1}{x^n+1}\ge 0$ ?

Comment: @Lucas That wasn't my goal, but to remain *only* with the integral of $\;\dfrac1{x^n+1}\;$ , from which we can very easily prove the inequality $\;I_n\ge I_{n+1}\;$

Comment: so you want to less $x^n$ at the numerator to be more easily to demonstrate, I've right?

Comment: Well, in this case yes as the algebraic decomposition of $\;\dfrac{x^n}{x^n+1}\;$ yields that and that way is easier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22435/discussion-between-lucas-and-timbuc).

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

1)We have $x\in [0,1]\Rightarrow x^{n+1}\le x^n$. Then prove that $\frac{x^n}{x^n+1}\ge\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^{n+1}+1}$. You can use the fact that for any real number $a\neq -1$ we have $\frac{a}{a+1}=1-\frac{1}{a+1}$.

2)For any $x>0$ we have $2x-1<2x$